# How to reference a columns within the same table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table `Receipt` with columnsn

```
| ORNUMBER | Description | Quantity | Date |
```

I want to reference my `Quantity` and `Date` columns to `Description`.

For example I dropped the column `Description` both the `Quantity` and `Date` will also be dropped

What's the script for that? Thanks!.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. There is no command that will drop an (entire) column automatically when you drop another one (and never will be, because you can easily do that manually). Dropping a column means removing it entirely from the table, do you really mean that? Do you maybe mean that you want to delete the row when you modify the row (e.g. set `null`)? Or do you maybe want to set the values `Quantity` and `Date` also `null` when you set `Description` to `null`? Maybe you could add some sample data to describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: I suppose that you want to null Quantity and Date automatically when Description will be nulled, is that right? I think [trigger](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html) is what can help you with your task

Answer (score 0):

Below is the procedure you can use,

```
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE Receipt DROP COLUMN Description;
END;

DECLARE 
    del_columns INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO del_columns
        FROM dba_tab_columns
        WHERE OWNER = 'user_name'
        AND table_name = 'Receipt'
        AND column_name = 'Description'
IF(del_columns = 0)
THEN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE Receipt DROP column Quantity, Date;
END IF;
END;
```

Explanation:

- In the first begin statement, Description column is deleted
- In the second statement, a temporary integer value del_column in declared
- From the system table, table name and column name is declared as a condition and the count is displayed
- If the count is 0, then description column is not available and then other two other columns will be deleted. If you get 1, then that column is available and two other columns will not be deleted
- You can also use all_tab_columns table in the where condition that provides all the table name apart from that user it it is super user
- Make sure you provide your owner name in the where condition